# How to get selected values from JSON output

Tags: json, jq

From the output shown, I was looking for `solr : xcfrtgyhujikolpu` in a shell script:

```
[{"username":"zookeeper","password":"sdfrtghuioklhq"}, 
 {"username":"solr","password":"xcfrtgyhujikolpu"}]
```

I tried:

```
|  jq -r .[].password
```

Comment: What went wrong with your `jq` command?  It produced nothing?  It produced too much?  Where did you restrict the output to `username` = `solr`?  Where did you specify that you wanted the value from `username` and the value from `password`?

Answer (score 1):

```
.[] | select( .username == $username ) | .username + " : " + .password
```

Used as

```sh
jq --arg username solr -r '.[] | select( .username == $username ) | .username + " : " + .password'
```

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/fEkcRmZt9v)